# What is a slotted open ring with a thread called (like on bicycle brake levers)?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, terminology

I'm looking for a small ring that allows a thin cable to pass through but can also lock to close that opening, like on bicycle brake lever screws (shown below). However, I'm having trouble finding the part because I don't know what it's called.

[image]

Do they have an official/technical name?

Answer (score 7):

The term appears to be "[Adjusting Barrel](https://www.google.se/search?q=adjusting%20barrel&tbm=isch)" or "Barrel Adjuster".